# Actionscript 3.0 - Check if tiles are left

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5, flashdevelop

I'm a student and I'm working on my final project but I'm stuck. I'm in a point of my action script that I can not find a solution for my problem. I've searched the web, almost read all the websites that could help me. But here is my problem.

I have to make a flash game in action script. I'm almost done but I can not find how to add the code that validate that there are no tiles left to choose.

*Can some help with where I have to place the code to check if there are no more tiles on the stage? And also what code do I have to use?*

And also when it has checked if there are no tiles left and there are non left it has to go to a second frame where it ask to play again or go back to the homescreen.

My code:

```
package {
// importing classes
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.text.*;
// end of importing classes
public class Main extends Sprite {
    private var pickedTiles:Array = new Array();  
    private const NUMBER_OF_TILES:uint=24;
    private var pause_game:Timer;
    private var canPick:Boolean=true;
    // scorebord
    private static const pointsForMatch:int = 100; 
    private static const pointsForMiss:int = -5; 
    private var gameScoreField:TextField; 
    private var gameScore:int; 
    public function Main() {
        gameScoreField = new TextField();
        addChild(gameScoreField); 
        gameScoreField.x = 810; 
        gameScoreField.y = 50;
        gameScoreField.width = 200;
        var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        format.size = 50;
        gameScoreField.defaultTextFormat = format;
        gameScoreField.textColor = 0xFF0000;

        // variables and constants
        // no more NUMBER_OF_TILES here
        const TILES_PER_ROW:uint=6;
        var tiles:Array=new Array();
        var tile:tile_movieclip;
        // end of variables and constants
        // tiles creation loop
        for (var i:uint=0; i<NUMBER_OF_TILES; i++) 
        {
            tiles.push(Math.floor(i/2));
        }
        trace("My tiles: "+tiles);
        // end of tiles creation loop
        // shuffling loop
        var swap,tmp:uint;
        for (i=NUMBER_OF_TILES-1; i>0; i--) 
        {
            swap=Math.floor(Math.random()*i);
            tmp=tiles[i];
            tiles[i]=tiles[swap];
            tiles[swap]=tmp;
        }
        trace("My shuffled tiles: "+tiles);
        // end of shuffling loop
        // tile placing loop
        for (var i:uint=0; i<NUMBER_OF_TILES; i++) 
        {
            tile=new tile_movieclip();
            addChild(tile);

            tile.cardType=tiles[i];
            tile.x=5+(tile.width+5)*(i%TILES_PER_ROW);
            tile.y=5+(tile.height+5)*(Math.floor(i/TILES_PER_ROW));
            tile.gotoAndStop(NUMBER_OF_TILES/2+1);
            tile.buttonMode=true;
            tile.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onTileClicked);
        }
        // end of tile_placing_loop
    }
        private function onTileClicked(e:MouseEvent) 
        {
            if(canPick)
            {
                var picked:tile_movieclip=e.currentTarget as tile_movieclip;
                trace("you picked a "+e.currentTarget.cardType);
                // checking if the current tile has already been picked
                if (pickedTiles.indexOf(picked)==-1) {
                    pickedTiles.push(picked);
                    picked.gotoAndStop(picked.cardType+1);
                }
                // end checking if the current tile has already been picked
                // checking if we picked 2 tiles
                if (pickedTiles.length==2) 
                {
                    canPick=false;
                    pause_game=new Timer(1000,1);
                    pause_game.start();
                    if (pickedTiles[0].cardType==pickedTiles[1].cardType) 
                    {
                        // tiles match!!
                        trace("tiles match!!!!");
                        pause_game.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,removeTiles);
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        // tiles do not match
                        trace("tiles do not match");
                        pause_game.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,resetTiles);
                    }
                    // no more pickedTiles = new Array();
                }
                // end checking if we picked 2 tiles
            }
        }
        private function removeTiles(e:TimerEvent) 
        {
            pause_game.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,removeTiles);
            pickedTiles[0].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onTileClicked);
            pickedTiles[1].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onTileClicked);
            removeChild(pickedTiles[0]);
            removeChild(pickedTiles[1]);
            pickedTiles = new Array();
            gameScore += pointsForMatch; // +100 points
            showGameScore(); // shows new score
            canPick = true;
        }
        private function resetTiles(e:TimerEvent) 
        {
            pause_game.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,resetTiles);
            pickedTiles[0].gotoAndStop(NUMBER_OF_TILES/2+1);
            pickedTiles[1].gotoAndStop(NUMBER_OF_TILES/2+1);
            pickedTiles = new Array();
            gameScore += pointsForMiss; // -5 points
            showGameScore(); //shows new score
            canPick = true;
        }
    public function showGameScore() 
    {
        gameScoreField.text = String(gameScore);
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consider this more of a quick 'hack', but since you know the amount of tiles, you could create a counter. Then every time a pair of tiles are removed from the board, add 2 to the counter (one for each tile). When the counter matches the number of tiles you have at the start, it would mean all tiles have been matched and thus removed from the board.

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be that since you keep the tiles in the tiles array, You can have something that as the user clicks on the tiles you remove the items from the Array with the splice property so when the array.length property is at zero you can end the game.

p.s not sure if splice property is the one you need but here is the actionscript website that tell you all about arrays and their properties  [ActionScript 3 Site](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html)